# Yii2\php вывести не совпадающие значения из массива

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Доброе время суток, я новичок в данном фреймворке.
У меня есть затруднение в получении не совпадающих значений. Если есть совпадения значений в колонке apartment_id не выводить.
Попробую привести пример: если в столбце есть совпадение apartment_id = 12, нужно вывести другие значение

Есть таблица **заявок**

[image: Mysql таблица заявок]

я создаю два запроса

```php
$request = Request::find()
    ->select([
    'request.id',                           //номер заявки
    'request.apartment_id'                  //квартира
    ])
    ->where(['=', 'created_by', 12])        //человек который создал
    ->andwhere(['=', 'type', 'connection']) //тип подключения
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

второй запрос делает выборку всех записей в этой же таблице.

```php
$request_all = Request::find()
    ->select([
    'request.id', 
    'request.apartment_id' 
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Каким можно способом решить данную задачу. Вроде как можно использовать массив (array_intersect_assoc), но это не точно.

Или только как-то через foreach?

```php
  foreach($request as $check){
       $request_all = Request::find()
          ->select([
              'request.id', 
              'request.apartment_id' 
            ])
            ->where(['=', 'apartment_id', $check['apartment_id']])
            ->one();
       и что нужно делать? Потому как показывает только равное
   }
```

заранее спасибо

Comment: "Если есть совпадения значений в колонке apartment_id не выводить." вы думаете это кому-то понятно? давайте примеры конкретные, если сформулировать словами не можете

Comment: хорошо попробую привести пример:  если в столбце есть совпадение apartment_id = 12, нужно вывести другие значение, кроме этих (совпадений)